# How can I iterate over multiple lists at the same time in Perl?

Tags: perl, arrays, list

I need to create a text file **(aptest.s)** that Ican use to read into another program. I am using Perl because I have a large list to work from. My code is as follows (which does not give the desired output - shown after code and actual output). Any help would be appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
chdir("D://projects//SW Model ODME");
@link = ("319-116264||319-118664","320-116380||320-116846","321-119118||321-119119","322-115298||322-119087");
@link1 = ("116264-319||118664-319","116380-320||116846-320","119118-321||119119-321","115298-322||119087-322");
open (FSAS, ">>aptest.s");
foreach $link (@link) {
    foreach $link1 (@link1){
    print FSAS "other code \n";
    print FSAS "PATHLOAD SELECTLINK=(Link=".$link."), VOL[2]=MW[1] \n";
    print FSAS "PATHLOAD SELECTLINK=(Link=".$link1."), VOL[3]=MW[2] \n";
    print FSAS "other code \n";
}
}
```

**Actual Output** :

```
other output
PATHLOAD SELECTLINK=(Link=319-116264||319-118664), VOL[2]=MW[1] 
PATHLOAD SELECTLINK=(Link=116264-319||118664-319), VOL[3]=MW[2] 
other output 

other output
PATHLOAD SELECTLINK=(Link=**319-116264||319-118664**), VOL[2]=MW[1] 
PATHLOAD SELECTLINK=(Link=**116380-320||116846-320**),      VOL[3]=MW[2] 
other output
```

**Desired Output**

```
other output
PATHLOAD SELECTLINK=(Link=319-116264||319-118664), VOL[2]=MW[1] 
PATHLOAD SELECTLINK=(Link=116264-319||118664-319), VOL[3]=MW[2] 
other output

other output
PATHLOAD SELECTLINK=(Link=**320-116380||320-116846**), VOL[2]=MW[1] 
PATHLOAD SELECTLINK=(Link=**116380-320||116846-320**), VOL[3]=MW[2] 
other output
```

Answer (score 21):

See **`each_array`** in [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::MoreUtils):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils qw( each_array );

my @x = qw( A B C D E F );
my @y = (10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15);

my $it = each_array( @x, @y );
while ( my ($x, $y) = $it->() ) {
    print "$x = $y\n";
}
__END__
```

Comment: Yes.  That's probably what the questioner needs.

Answer (score 4):

I *think* you're trying to create *four* separate blocks, with each element from the `link` array associated with the corresponding element from the `link2` array?

However you're actually outputting *sixteen* blocks, one for each *combination* of `link` and `link1`.

Instead try:

```
foreach $i (0 .. $#link) {

   $link = $link[$i];
   $link1 = $link1[$i];

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Reading your question, it was difficult to tell what you really wanted to know.  I believe Sinan Unur is correct, and that you want to iterate simultaneously over two arrays.  As he says,  List::MoreUtils provides the very handy `each_array()` function.

It is also simple to iterate over one or more arrays by index.

You can generate a list of indexes for use with a normal for loop.  This uses `$#` to get the index of the last value in the array.

```
for ( 0..$#array ) { ... }
```

Or you can use a C-style for loop to generate your indexes.  This uses the fact that an array evaluated in scalar context returns the number of elements.

```
for ( my $i=0; $i<@array; $i++ ) { ... }
```

It could also be written using `$#`:

```
for ( my $i=0; $i<=$#array; $i++ ) { ... }
```

Upon reading your code, it was clear that you aren't familiar with [Perl's quoting operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators).  Using them effectively makes your scripts much easier to write and read.

In a friendly spirit, please allow me to tidy your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Always:
use strict;
use warnings;

#my $TARGET_DIR  = 'D://projects//SW Model ODME';
my $TARGET_DIR  = '.';

my $TARGET_FILE = 'aptest.s';

# Using qw() makes long lists of 
# literals easier to type and read.
# Consider finding better names than link and link1.
# Something that describes the relationship between
# the two arrays.
my @link = qw(
    319-116264||319-118664
    320-116380||320-116846
    321-119118||321-119119
    322-115298||322-119087
);

my @link1 = qw(
    116264-319||118664-319
    116380-320||116846-320
    119118-321||119119-321
    115298-322||119087-322
);

# check the results of chdir.  
chdir($TARGET_DIR) 
    or die "Unable to enter $TARGET_DIR - $!\n";

# Use a lexical filehandle.
# Use 3 arg open
# Check the results of open - you need to know if it fails.
open (my $fsas, '>>', $TARGET_FILE)
    or die "Unable to open $TARGET_FILE - $!\n";

# Verify that the link arrays are both sized appropriately.
die "Link arrays are not the same size."
    unless @link == @link1;

# Loop over the indexes of the array.
# For very (very) large arrays it is 
# more efficient to use a C-style for loop:
#   for( my $i = 0; $i < @link; $i++ ) {
foreach my $i (0..$#link) {
    my $link  = $link[$i];
    my $link1 = $link1[$i];

    print $fsas Get_Link_Text($link, $link1);
}

# Broke out your formatting code into a routine for readability.
# Used a heredoc to make the formatting easier to read.
# Also, took advantage of variable interpolation in the heredoc to further
# improve readability.
# I preserved the whitespace at the end of lines, is it really necessary?
sub Get_Link_Text {
    my $link = shift;
    my $link1 = shift;

    return <<"--END_TEXT--"; 
RUN PGM=HWYLOAD 
MATI=daily_trucks.MAT  
NETI=FAF_Network_V11.net  
NETO=MiamiDade.NET 
PARAMETERS MAXITERS=1, GAP=0.001, COMBINE=EQUI  
FUNCTION {   
TC[1] = T0*(1+0.15*(V/100)^(4))}    
FUNCTION V = (VOL[1]) 
PHASE=ILOOP 
PATHLOAD PATH=TIME, MW[1]=MI.1.1, SELECTLINK=(Link=$link), VOL[2]=MW[1] 
PATHLOAD PATH=TIME, MW[2]=MI.1.1, SELECTLINK=(Link=$link1), VOL[3]=MW[2] 
ENDPHASE  
ENDRUN 


--END_TEXT--
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and the code to make it more readable and  useful.

Answer (score 0):

Can you reduce the size of your code and example data while still reproducing the error?  I can't immediately see the difference between the actual and expected output.

Sometimes, finding a minimal set of code and data that causes a problem will make the solution obvious.

Looking a bit more carefully, there's only one bit of output code that is variable:

```
print FSAS "PATHLOAD PATH=TIME, MW[1]=MI.1.1, SELECTLINK=(Link=".$link."), VOL[2]=MW[1] \n";
print FSAS "PATHLOAD PATH=TIME, MW[2]=MI.1.1, SELECTLINK=(Link=".$link1."), VOL[3]=MW[2] \n";
```

Your bug is likely to be there.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your comments and suggestions. I have made my code more readable and appreciate your input.