# 2 arrays in a single foreach - perl

Tags: arrays, perl, foreach

I suck at perl as you can probably tell... I am using a script to apply changes to a Cisco device using Net::Application::Session. I have 2 arrays, 1 is the interface and 1 is the interface description. I need the commands "$s->cmd[]" to be entered like so:

```
$s->cmd("interface $configDescription");
$s->cmd("description >> WAP - $desName <<");
```

But I cannot figure out how to do it with a foreach statement. Below is what I am currently doing, this only changes the last line in the Array. Please Advise... I am a noob to this site, if this isn't enough information please tell me what is needed. Thank you.

```
foreach $configDescription (@changeme) {
   foreach $desName (@changename) {
      $s->cmd("interface $configDescription");
      $s->cmd("description >> WAP - $desName <<");
   };
};
```

Comment: It sounds like the answer to this question should put you on the right track: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822563/how-can-i-iterate-over-multiple-lists-at-the-same-time-in-perl

Comment: Are you talking about using each_array?

Comment: Thanks, that example worked, however I am looking to do this without using the List::MoreUtils module, without using any module.

Comment: @Matt, that's a dumb requirement. Less and less of Perl is available outside of modules. The idea that code from CPAN is bad but code from SO is ok is even sillier.

Comment: you can always just copy the code from the module you don't want to use...

Comment: @ikegame I get what your saying, I am putting this code in a Network Automation system that runs perl, I have not yet figured out how to load modules into this system ;).

Comment: Only using Net::Application::Session as testing on my perl box before I migrate it to the Network Automation system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are called parallel arrays.

```
for my $i (0..$#changeme) {
   my $configDescription = $changeme[$i];
   my $desName           = $changename[$i];
   $s->cmd("interface $configDescription");
   $s->cmd("description >> WAP - $desName <<");
}
```

Or: (destructive)

```
while (@changeme) {
   my $configDescription = shift(@changeme);
   my $desName           = shift(@changename);
   $s->cmd("interface $configDescription");
   $s->cmd("description >> WAP - $desName <<");
}
```

Comment: The top one is simply finding the length of the two arrays, then looping thought them via the index. Simple, easy to understand, and fast. In fact, it's faster than using `map` twice.

Comment: Why is the second one called destructive?

Comment: @user13107, A destructive algorithm is one that changes its inputs. In this case, it empties `@change` and `@changename`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, if you're as fond of map-grep chains as I am.

```
map { 
    $s->cmd("interface $_->[0]");
    $s->cmd("description >> WAP - $_->[1] <<");
} 
map { [ $changeme[$_], $changename[$_] ] } 
0..$#changeme
;
```

Comment: That's a whole lot of useless work. `map { $s->cmd("interface $changeme[$_]"); $s->cmd("description >> WAP - $changename[$_] <<");
} 0..$#changeme;` would be way better.

Comment: But it would still miss out on the memory savings and speed boost of an actual counting loop. `for (0..$#changeme) { $s->cmd("interface $changeme[$_]"); $s->cmd("description >> WAP - $changename[$_] <<"); }`

Answer (score 1):

```
use Algorithm::Loops 'MapCar'; # or MapCarE, MapCarU, etc.

MapCar {
    my ($configDescription, $desName) = @_;
    $s->cmd("interface $configDescription");
    $s->cmd("description >> WAP - $desName <<");
} \@changeme, \@changename;
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought i'd add this on as another solution just for documentation purposes.

```
 use List::MoreUtils qw( each_array );

 my $it = each_array( @changeme, @changename );
              while ( my ($configDescription, $desName) = $it->() ) {
                 $s->cmd("interface $configDescription");
                 $s->cmd("description >> WAP - $desName <<");
              };
```