# Join elements of two arrays and create a result array in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

Basically what i need if i have two arrays like below:

```
my @a=("a","b","c");
my @z=("x","y","z");
```

I want the result array to be:

```
("a x","b y","c z")
```

pre condition is the number is elements in both the array are always same.
post condtion is the order should be same as the original array order.
i have written a simple loop

```
my $i;
for($i=0;$i<scalar(@a);$i++)
{
push(@result,$a[$i]." ".$z[$i]);
}
```

And the above works.
But is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: BTW, `for my $i (0 .. $#a)` is more readable and does not keep $i in scope where not needed.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you're using the C-style `for` loop then you can probably improve matters by switching to `foreach`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `map`, which is a loop in disguise:

```
my @result = map "$a[$_] $z[$_]", 0 .. $#a;
```

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822563/how-can-i-iterate-over-multiple-lists-at-the-same-time-in-perl). You can use `each_array` from `List::MoreUtils` to make it a little cleaner to iterate over two arrays at a time.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use List::MoreUtils qw/each_array/;

my @a = qw/a b c/;
my @b = qw/x y z/;
my $it = each_array(@a, @b);

my @result;

while (my ($x, $y) = $it->()) {
        push @result, $x . " " . $y;
}
```

Comment: These utilities are a nice approach to know about.  In this case, I think `pairwise` would be a better choice. `@result = pairwise { "$a $b" } @a, @z;`